# Invoke Java via Batch File with Filepath Arguments

Tags: java, batch-file, argument-passing, command-line-arguments

I'm having an issue getting files loaded into an app called GCS, by dragging them onto the executable. GCS can be invoked on Windows with a bat file, which goes like this:

```
@echo off
start javaw -Xmx256M -jar "GURPS Character Sheet.app/Contents/Resources/Java/GCS.jar" %*
```

If I hard code a filepath in place of the batch argument wildcard (with quotes), it works. If I run the debugger with a filepath argument it works. If I echo `%`, it gives me the correct filename with quotes around it. If I add quotes around `%` it still breaks.

I have a disconnect here between the batch file and Java, and I'm at a loss. Does anyone recognize this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a shortcut to the batch file to get drag and drop on invocation to work. But now I can't open with a double click outside of the bat's directory. :(